# Business Objects: Identifying cells with multiple words

Tags: database, business-objects

I'm currently using (SAP) Business Objects to build a report.

I want to be able to identify rows where a person has both their first and middle name in the same cell.

For example: Cell A1 = "JOHN" Cell B1 = "THOMAS FREDRIC"

What I want to be able to do is only show the cells that include two names in one, e.g Cell B1.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build yourself a variable, something like the following should do,

=Pos(Trim([First Names]); " ")

It Trim(s) any leading and trailing spaces from your First Names column and then returns the Pos(ition) of the first space it finds in the column. So any result other than 0 indicates two or more names in the column. Once you can identify the rows you're after there are a number of options (which I can't currently remember the details of) open to you.